# Table of Contents with Appendix short and a new toc with detailed appendix?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I would like to include the first level (chapter) of my appendix in my big toc at the beginning of my document, but also would like to have a separate toc in detail for the appendix itself at the beginning of it. I tried to use packages like etoc or minitoc but cannot bring it to work.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I}
\chapter{Chapter II}
\section{Section I}

\appendix
\vspace*{\fill}
{\huge\bfseries\textsf{Anhang}\par}%Introduction of the appendix
\vspace*{\fill}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang}%Appendix in TOC
\newpage
\addchap{A~~Appendix 1}
\addsec{A.1~Appendix 1, First Section}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KOMA-Script class `scrbook` loads and uses package `tocbasic` for ToC, LoF, LoT etc. So you could use `\DeclareNewTOC` to declare a new ToC for the appendix content. In the appendix you have to redefine `\ext@toc` to the extansion of the new TOC.

Unfortunately I do not know where the appendix content should be printed. Maybe you want

```latex
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
  owner=\jobname
]{atoc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\useappendixtoc}{%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{atoc}%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{hypersetup}{}{%
    \hypersetup{bookmarkstype=atoc}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\appendix{%
  \addchap{\appendixname}
  \listoftoc*{atoc}
  \useappendixtoc
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I}
\chapter{Chapter II}
\section{Section I}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix 1}
\section{Appendix 1, First Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Or with an additional appendix page:

```latex
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
  owner=\jobname,
  listname={Inhalt des Anhangs},
]{atoc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\useappendixtoc}{%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{atoc}%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{hypersetup}{}{%
    \hypersetup{bookmarkstype=atoc}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\appendix{%
  %\setkomafont{part}{\usekomafont{chapter}}%
  %\renewcommand*{\raggedpart}{\raggedright}%
  \let\addparttocentry\addchaptertocentry
  \addpart{\appendixname}
  \useappendixtoc
  \listofatocs
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I}
\chapter{Chapter II}
\section{Section I}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix 1}
\section{Appendix 1, First Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]