New Section Command for new TOC
I have the following structure in my document:

TOC1
Section1
Section2
Subsection2.1
Subsection2.2
Section3
TOC2
Subsection3.1
Subsubsections3.1.x
Subsection3.2
Subsubsections3.2.x

I want the TOC1 only to include all Sections and Subsections2.x. The TOC2 must include Subsections3.x and all Subsubsections in this Section3.
So I declared a new TOC2 (\DeclareNewTOC). I thought that I could now declare a new section command (\DeclareNewSectionCommand for Subsections3.x) and link this to the new TOC2 to stop them from appearing in the TOC1. But how can I do this? I see no option to link the new Section Command to my new TOC2 neither in DeclareNewSectionCommand nor in DeclareTOCStyleEntry.
It works with the renewcommand but I think I'm overlooking something very simple here. There is a remarkbox example in the documentation which defines a new environment with the NewTOC command. Is this possible with Sections?
MWE:
\documentclass[%
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a4,
german
]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{fontspec}

%\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} %Tiefe des Inhaltsverzeichnisses bis zur dritten Ebene
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}


\DeclareNewTOC[%
owner=\jobname,%
listname={Test},%
]{toc2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\listoftoc*{toc2}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{toc2}
\makeatother
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{toc}
\makeatother
\end{document}



A minimal working example would IMHO help, to understand what you want and also to test our idea and show a suggestion. But it sounds like either something like the appendix ToC, shown on the KOMA-Script homepage or an older DTK article. In this case, you don't need new section command, but only define a new ToC and redefine \toc@ext.

Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585195/277964

I add a MWE and I work with the renewcommand. But is this the only (and easiest) solution?

Easiest or not it opinion based. It is a solution and also one, the KOMA-Script author recommends for split ToC. But if you want, you can also redefine \addsubsectiontocentry or \addtocentrydefault. You even could redefine \addtocontents. But I see no reason, why not redefining \ext@toc.

Until an official KOMA solution appears here is how one can do that with etoc package:
\documentclass[%
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a4,
german
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
\etocsettagdepth{aftersection3}{section}
\tableofcontents

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\etocdepthtag.toc{aftersection3}
\etocignoredepthtags
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}


and adding
\etocsettocstyle{}{}

right before the \localtableofcontents would avoid "Contents" seen in screen capture above.

I think there must be an official way to use KOMA interface in this example to avoid the Contents (rather than \etocsettocstyle{}{}) but not sure.  I had seen somethin in etoc doc, let's dig into it...(some time later) I see an exemple in section 27. Testing the compatibility mode which uses KOMAoptions then \etocclasstocstyle and \etocstandardlines (not sure if that one is needed, must be default here).  If there is a KOMAoption of the type toc=notitle this should work. (untested)
